# Ubuntu Mate Macbook hangs on shutdown and reboot

Tags: suspend, shutdown, macbook

I have just installed the latest 32bit Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on a 2006 Macbook 1,1

It hangs when shutdown or rebooted either from the menu or from the terminal.

```
sudo halt
```

or

```
sudo reboot
```

On reboot, the shutdown progresses ok but on restart it hangs before it gets to the grub screen. The screen goes black with the backlight on and the fan spins at maximum but startup does not progress further. If I choose shutdown the process hangs indefinately at the splash screen and it is impossible to see the messages by pressing the arrow keys. Ifp the computer is given a hard shutdown with the power key, the shutdown and startup progresses fine.

It also doesn't 'wake up' from sleep.

Are there any changes to the configurations I can make to get this working? Apart from this, it works well and I want to keep on using it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what caused it but after a few cycles and updates it has fixed itself. Go Ubuntu!